# Tweaking and repackaging an air app

Tags: air, adobe, packaging, tweak

I have an AIR app that I'd like to tweak a little bit. I just have the .air package, no original source tree.

I noticed it's just a ZIP file with contents. When I manipulate the contents, AIR no longer accepts the package. I assume this is because the META-INF/AIR/hash and the signature are no longer up-to-date.

Can I create a new (self-signed) AIR package from the modified tree? How? I've been looking at the adt tool but can't find much about this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using adt works fine. First create the keystore to self-sign with:

`adt.bat -certificate -cn dummy 1024-RSA test.p12 password`

Then create the package:

`adt.bat -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore test.p12 -tsa none -target air test.air META-INF/AIR/application.xml`

... and then list all resources to be included in the package.